# Multiple arrays in a while

Tags: php, mysql

I need a help to solution that: I need to do a table with a value of 4 different my sql arrays, like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from tbl_work where work_category = 1 
 ORDER BY note DESC");

$sql2 = mysql_query("select * from tbl_work where work_category = 2 
 ORDER BY note DESC");

$sql3 = mysql_query("select * from tbl_work where work_category = 3 
 ORDER BY note DESC");

$sql4 = mysql_query("select * from tbl_work where work_category = 4 
 ORDER BY note DESC");
```

And I make four arrays with each one:

```
$find1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$find2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);

$find3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3);

$find4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4);
```

Now, I need to do 10 times, a table with value of all of that arrays, but need to be order, without repeat and side by side, split in category.

Like 4 columns, each have order and different value of `work_category`.

Thank you!

Comment: You gotta [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) out your code man

Answer (score 6):

Why not change the query to get all results at once:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_work WHERE work_category IN (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY note DESC
```

P.S: Use `PDO`, `mysql_*` are deprecated.

Comment: *"P.S: Use PDO, mysql_* are deprecated"* - The use of `mysqli_` and/or PDO are not safeguards against SQL injection; not on their own that is. Using [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will.

Comment: I think he also wants them ordered by `note` per category not just a flat order so he'll need to do `ORDER BY work_category, note DESC`